# Plumber: getting request body/schema in UI

Tags: r, plumber

I'm trying to make a R plumber api that has a example request body/schema in the *docs* UI interface, similar to what is shown in these videos (https://www.rstudio.com/resources/rstudioconf-2019/democratizing-r-with-plumber-apis/ , or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0Th2QRZ7Rk )

My attempt to set the body using yaml, similar to the second video is below. However, I don't see any body example/schema when I open the docs [image of response to pressing "try it out" + "execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThohP.png). I was hoping to see a Request body with "edit value" and "schema" options.

plumber.R

```
#* @apiTitle test API
#* @apiDescription an api


#* test
#* @put /test_json
function(res, req){
  new_data <- req$body
  return(new_data)
}


function(pr){
  pr %>% pr_set_api_spec(yaml::read_yaml(paste0(getwd(), "/openapi.yaml")))
}
```

openapi.yaml

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Sample API
  description: Optional multiline or single-line description in [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/help/) or HTML.
  version: 0.1.9
servers:
  - url: http://api.example.com/v1
    description: Optional server description, e.g. Main (production) server
  - url: http://staging-api.example.com
    description: Optional server description, e.g. Internal staging server for testing
paths:
  /test_json:
    post:
      summary: 'A test'
      responses:
        default:
          description: Default response
      parameters: []
      requestBody:
      description: some data
      required: true
      content:
        application/json:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
          number:
            type: number
            title: "A number"
            example: 40
```

Answer (score 1):

I may have found at least one solution to this

plumber.R

```
v <- list(number = 40)

#* @apiTitle test API
#* @apiDescription an api

#* test
#* @put /test_json
#* @param input:object
function(input = v){
  new_data <- unlist(v)
  return(new_data)
}
```

gives me the desired body
[body in docs][1]

I found some other examples of how this could be done here https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/issues/768
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOhGw.png

Comment: When doing put with body, I access with req$body (which looks like a nested list in R) - do you know how this can work with the input:object param? req:object gives an empty list (i.e. nested lists not supported by Plumber swagger documentation).